# @pathparam along with POST payload for apache-cxf webservice

Tags: rest, web-services, apache-camel, cxf, path-parameter

My interface that is implemented by my impl class looks something like this

```java
@POST
@Path("/callA/{A}")
public FObj invokeA(@PathParam("A") int a,FObj fobj);
```

And my `customRouteBuilder` is routing the request to the above exposed service

```java
.choice().when().simple("${header.operationName} == 'CallA'")
        .to("bean:BeanA?method=invokeA")
```

But when I hit the service from Rest client by setting the object from payload and also path param i get 500 Internal server error.

> org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange
>   Caused by: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: int but has value: com.dev.tp.FObj

Answer (score 0):

When you hit the service, a value to be set to `header.operationName` would be `invokeA`, if you are using CXFRS Component (i guess you are). `@PathParam` is from jaxrs specification. Camel knows nothing about it. When you invoke a method with two parameters, it tries to cast body payload to first parameter, and you see an exception.

I recomment you to take a look at [this article](https://capgemini.github.io/development/creating-a-cxf-restful-service-in-camel-blueprint/)